# RX AutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm trying to build an filter control using RX and WPF. 
So I have a textbox and a listbox. 
On start up the listbox has 100 contact names and the user can type in a name to filter the list.

Question is how can I build up an text stream (key inputs) and then publish. This should be Time sensitive so I guess only after 750milliseconds if a key input hasnt been detected then the filter may be performed.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic outline would looks like so

1. textbox keydown event converted to an IO
2. throttling of the keystrokes, so that we don't search while the user is actually typing
3. Do the search
4. Place the the search results onto the list box

Here's some pseudo-code -

```
 var keysIO =   Observable.FromEvent<KeyDownEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
                                    h => new KeyDownEventHandler(h),
                                    h => btn.KeyDown += h,
                                    h => btn.KeyDown -= h));

 var searchResults = keysIO.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.750),Scheduler.Dispatcher);

 searchResults.Subscribe(sr => {  lb.Clear(); lb.AddRange(sr); });
```

@Andy, `Throttle` won't kick off a search every 750ms, only after the user has stopped typing for 750ms. Try this in LinqPad.

```
   Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
   .Do(ii =>  "keystroke".Dump())
   .Take(10)
   .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.750))
   .Select(ttl => "search")
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back, problem with Throttle is it will kick in every 0.750, I need something to kick in when no key press has been made for 0.750.

Comment: @Andy - `Throttle` waits for _timeoutSpan_ period of time before emitting the value. If a new value is received in that time, the _timeoutSpan_ wait resets.

Comment: How can I test this in LinqPad? It does not recognize `Observable` class.

Answer (score 2):

What Scott Weinstein is suggesting is correct.

Additionally, since you want to affect a Gui control, you have to make sure to either ObserveOn the Dispatcher or use the scheduler somewhere before you subscribe, to get you back to the dispatcher thread.

This worked for me:

```
 Observable.FromEvent<TextChangedEventArgs>(TextBox, "TextChanged")
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.75), Scheduler.Dispatcher)
                .Select(obs => TextBox.Text)
                .Subscribe(TextChangedTo);
```

Now in the `TextChangedTo(text)` method you would populate your list with contact names.

Comment: Always prefer an `IDispatcher` overload to using `ObserverOnDispatcher`. The former _keeps you on_ the UI thread, the latter _moves you back onto_ the UI thread.

Comment: Of course, if it weren't for the Throttle, you wouldn't need to delegate back to the dispatcher because you would have never left it. Any of the Rx methods that utilize a timer, including Throttle, Interval, BufferWithTime, etc, require the managing of threads.

Answer (score 1):

On new versions of Rx the Scheduler.Dispatcher has disappeared and FromEvent seems that does not work well with WPF, so, for anyone that needs a solution today here you have a working solution for a textbox named FilterText:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
    h => this.FilterText.TextChanged += h,
    h => this.FilterText.TextChanged -= h)
    .Throttle(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 750))
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(t => DoFiltering(this.FilterText.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a full example [here](http://www.japf.fr/2011/02/techdays-2011-rx-talk-slides-and-source-code/), with slides and source code