# Autocomplete: Asynchronous population with WCF using threads

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have an "autocomplete" textbox that will invoke a WCF method each time a key is pressed.
The WCF server, in turn, will run an SQL query, return the first 15 results and send them.
However, this results in a noticeable latency when typing in the box.

What I'm about to do instead is this:

- Create a new thread when a text_changed event is fired, make that thread wait 1000ms using Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds. During this waiting time, the thread can be stopped permanently.
- If it was not stopped, the thread will send the request to the server (and repopulate the auto complete box).
- As soon as a new "text_changed" event is fired, I will stop the current thread and start a new one.

Is there a better approach or is this the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to use the Rx (Reactive Extensions) framework to encapsulate automplete with some very interesting characteristics.

With Rx you get ability to compose (multiple event sources), throttle the user input so that you don't overwhelm the source, and on top of that you can ignore the old result if user typed more in the search box (TakeUntil).

More info:

[Rx: Curing your asynchronous programming blues](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/codefest/DC2010T0100-Keynote-Rx-curing-your-asynchronous-programming-blues)

[Curing the asynchronous blues with the Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/D/C5D669F9-01DF-4FAF-BBA9-29C096C462DB/Rx%20HOL%20.NET.pdf)

Example:

[SO: RX AutoCompleteBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438639/rx-autocompletebox)

```
RxProperty = Observable.FromEvent<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
        h => new TextChangedEventHandler(h),
        h => AssociatedObject.TextChanged += h,
        h => AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= h)

        .Select(t => ((TextBox)t.Sender).Text)

        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400))

        .SubscribeOnDispatcher()
        .Take(10)
        .TakeUntil(AssociatedObject.TextChanged );
```

Instead of FromEvent you can use FromAsync and use proxy Beginxxx Endxxx methods.

Answer (score 1):

So basically wait for 1 second for the user to stop typing before requesting results.

That's a good solution for conserving server resources, but you are actually adding latency by making the user wait for a minimum of 1000ms.

My guess is that your original issue was that this is a winforms app and the request you made was synchronous by default. As a result, the textbox wasn't accepting user input while the app was waiting for a response. Just making the call asynchronous should solve that issue without making the typing slower.

Comment: I see. Is there any option to make a WCF call asynchronous?

Comment: There are a few links with examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781932/async-call-to-wcf-with-c

Comment: Some direct WCF links here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-Implement-a-WCF-2090bec8